# Extracting bold text in a Google Slide, via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Apps Script, how to get the list (to be copied and paste in another place) of all the words in bold type contained in the shapes of a Google Slide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a bit of drilling down but here is an example of finding bold text in a Slide Presentation.

I tested it with a test presentation with normal and bold text scattered throughout.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let boldText = [];
    let presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
    let slides = presentation.getSlides();
    slides.forEach( slide => {
        let shapes = slide.getShapes();
        shapes.forEach( shape => {
            let text = shape.getText();
            let paragraphs = text.getParagraphs();
            paragraphs.forEach( paragraph => {
                let runs = paragraph.getRange().getRuns();
                runs.forEach( run => {
                    if( run.getTextStyle().isBold() ) {
                      boldText.push(run.asString());
                    }
                  }
                );
              }
            );
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Reference

- [SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app#getActivePresentation())
- [Presentation.getSlides()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getSlides())
- [Slide.getShapes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getShapes())
- [Shape.getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#getText())
- [TextRange.getParagraphs()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getParagraphs())
- [Paragraph.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/paragraph#getRange())
- [TextRange.getRuns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getRuns())
- [TextRange.getTextStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getTextStyle())
- [TextStyle.isBold()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#isBold())
- [Array.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

Comment: This really is a  great start, thank you very much!!! The resulting log specifies the timecodes and the mention "info" for each occurrence. How to get only relevant (bold) words? I simply need to copy and paste them elsewhere.

Comment: You could simply push them into an array.

Comment: Could you please show me just how to go about it, concretely. This will then be my last question.

Comment: I've shown how to save text to an array.